# xmlsec1 sign failed - id

Tags: xml-signature, xmlsec, xmlsec1

In the SignInfo node I have

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-132">...
```

It refers to the node below:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-132">
```

Command:

```
xmlsec1 --sign --output request-signed.xml --privkey-pem privatekey.pem raw_message.xml
```

I have this error:
    **func=xmlSecXPathDataExecute:file=xpath.c:line=273:obj=unknown:subj=xmlXPtrEval:error=5:libxml2 library function failed:expr=xpointer(id('Id-132'))**

Comment: Probably related to the ID being part of the wsu namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sign with ids references is necessary `--id-attr:` parameter. Example:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-132">

<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-132">
```

Command: `xmlsec1 --sign --output request-signed.xml --privkey-pem privatekey.pem --id-attr:Id raw_message.xml`

More information: https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/758-how-to-sign-xml-documents-using-xmldsig-xml-signature-